# Can't compile C program using Windows 7 command prompt and MinGW

Tags: c, gcc, windows-7, mingw

I am having a really tough time trying to compile this code running command prompt in Windows 7 using MinGW:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

    int num;
    num = 1;

    printf ("I am a simple ");
    printf ("computer. \n");
    printf ("My favorite number is %d because it is first. \n", num);

      
    return 0;
}
```

I run command prompt as administrator. I set the user path environmental variable (not the system path variable) to the local MinGW. I place first.c (this above source code) into C: directory.  I've tried the following commands with directory set to C:

```
gcc first.c

gcc C:/first.c
```

but get:

> gcc: error:  first.c: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried troubleshooting quite a bit using previous Stackoverflow questions and elsewhere, but just can't seem to get it.

Comment: Change directory of command prompt  to place where file is .

Comment: That's what I've been doing unfortunately. I place the file in C: directory and then set the directory in command prompt to C:, double checking with dir, putting in the aforementioned commands and I still get the error messages.

Comment: gcc C:/first.c wont work.   Instead first take cmd to C: and then just give command  gcc first.c. Error is because cmd is not able to locate or find file.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. Cmd is set to root directory C: and file is also saved in root directory of C. Then gcc first.c gives me same error.

Comment: @ameyCU but why `gcc c:/first.c` won't work?

Comment: I think it's possible I didn't set the user path environmental variable correctly. I have Variable:  `Path`  Value: `C:/MinGW/bin`   under User variables, where MinGW is saved to root C directory

Comment: path variable is set, so far I think, if it wasn't set, `cmd` couldn't recognize `gcc` command. As cmd recognized `gcc` command I don't thing path variable setting is the problem. @berderder problem is some where else I think. can you share the screen shot of your command prompt after running `gcc first.c` command in root C:?

Comment: Are you sure the file you trying to compile is `first.c` not `first.txt` ? Pardon me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sure, here's a screenshot, thanks: http://i.imgur.com/cjTxZqb.jpg?1

Comment: The root directory isn't really an appropriate place to be doing this.  Have you tried anywhere else, e.g., C:\Users\username?

Comment: everything's working fine in my pc, try restarting the pc. she has gone mad.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I've placed first.c in that exact location but get the same error message (and of course after setting directory in cmd to correct place). I've also reinstalled MinGW a couple of times to make sure that wasn't a problem. Maybe there is something wrong with the version or installation of MinGW that I've done.

Comment: @RafafTahsin: Haha, I wish. I've restarted the PC multiple times since first trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's most likely because you are saving it as a "Text Document", and not "All Files".
Open Wordpad, click on "File", click on "Save As", and select "All Files" in "Save as type" field.

Comment: That's exactly right. It was a bummer realizing this. Thank you.

Comment: @berderder: This is what happens, when you blindly adopt Windows asinine default configuration options; turn _off_ the one which says something like "_hide extensions of well known file types_", so you can see _exactly_ what every file is _really_ called.

Comment: @KeithMarshall yes!  That stupid gets turned off as first actions after a Windows install.  That, and 'Hide system files'.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. For some reason when I created a wordpad document for first.c, this would not compile correctly. I decided to try again using a notepad document and named the source code "second.c"

In my dir you can see both files.

[image: cmd screenshot]

second.c compiles correctly with

```
gcc second.c
```

I don't know why first.c is named "first.c.txt" in the dir and second.c is named "second.c" only without the ".txt". This seems to create the error.

second.c compiles correctly and I can execute the compiled program. Finally!